# Cannot use sprite sheet to add texture to RawImage?

Tags: unity, 2d, textures, spritesheet

I am basically trying to recreate this sample image

[image]

from this sprite sheet

[image]

([Source](https://opengameart.org/content/post-apocalyptic-expansion))

I split the sprite sheet in the sprite editor of unity, now I want to use the top left texture for ground. But when I add UI->Raw Image, I cannot add the split texture to the texture source. How do I add it as a texture? In the source it does not show the split assets but the full sprite sheet.

How do I add this one single texture? That I have already split in the unity sprite editor.

Comment: Why do you want to use it as a Raw Image instead of an Image or Sprite? Populating a Raw Image from a spritesheet is somewhat unusual — typically we resort to Raw Image only for content that's generated at runtime, like RenderTextures.

Comment: I dont know. I guess the unity game dev course I am following stated that textures are input as raw images. Is this wrong?

Comment: Depending on the context, they might have been saying that you can import any common image format into Unity, and it will handle converting it to a game-ready format. (So it's "raw" in the sense that you didn't need to do special baking steps before bringing it into your project, rather than the sense of the RawImage component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments state, `RawImage` is for showing textures, but what you have are sprites (a thin veneer over parts of a texture). You'll want to use `SpriteRenderer`s or `Image`s instead. I would recommend sprites over images, since you are building a game scene, not a user interface. Note that both images and sprites have the ability to tile their contents.